How to make a working cycle for files in Palantir?
I am trying to simplify my code in Palantir. My idea is to use for cycle with f-string to simplify the process instead of writing X-times the same code with different numbers of output/source_df.
This is my code:
@transform(
    output1=Output("output1"),
    output2=Output("output2"),
    source_df1=Input("source1"),
    source_df2=Input("source2")
)
def compute(output1, output2, source_df1, source_df2):
    for i in range(1, 1, 3):
        f"output{i}".write_dataframe(f"source_df{i}".dataframe().filter(
        f"source_df{i}".dataframe().SNAPSHOT_DATE >= "2024-09-18").coalesce(1),
        output_format="csv", options={
            'compression': 'gzip', 'header': "True"
        })

This leads to:
ValueError: Parameter 'inputs' of transform Transform(myproject.datasets.list_of_tables:compute)<> is not a transforms.api.Param


What you are looking for are transforms generators.
https://community.palantir.com/t/transforms-generator-providing-additional-parameter-for-every-transformation/581/2
Your code will then look like:
    @transform(
        ** inputs_and_outputs
    )
    def my_transform(ctx, **all_datasets):
         # Do what you want on those datasets, iterate over them, etc.


And the reason the initial code does not work is that it is treating text e.g. "output1" as if it is the variable named output1.
